# Java Exception Handling and Stack Trace

Tags: java, exception

I'm fairly new to exception handling and am looking for a little help with one particular exception. I have written a GUI program to determine a user's age based on their birthday. I want to handle the exception thrown if the user enters anything but a valid birthday. I think I have handled the exception thrown (NumberFormatException) properly yet the stack trace is still being displayed. Is there a way to prevent this or is it just part of how to exception is thrown/caught? (I am also new to posting on this site so I'd love any feedback on how I can make my posts better, thanks!)

Here is my code:

```
/*
This program was written to determine a users age based on the input of
their birthday and the current date. 
Written by Randy Egan for CSC161.
Some exception handling has been implemented when entering an invalid 
birthday.
*/ 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class AgeCalculator extends JFrame{

public static final int WIDTH = 600;
public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
public static final int LEFT = 450;
public static final int RIGHT = 250;
//these will be used to set positioning and size for the window

private JLabel enterBDayL, userAgeL;
private JTextField enterBDayTF, userAgeTF;
private JButton clearB, calculateB;
//these will be used to set up the GUI

private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

public AgeCalculator(){

  //start of GUI setup-

  setTitle("Age Calculator");

  enterBDayL = new JLabel("Enter your birthday in the form MM/DD/YYYY");
  userAgeL = new JLabel("Your current age is");

  enterBDayTF = new JTextField();
  userAgeTF = new JTextField();

  clearB = new JButton("Clear");
  calculateB = new JButton("Calculate");
  calculateB.addActionListener(new CalculateButtonHandler());
  clearB.addActionListener(new ClearButtonHandler());


  Container pane = getContentPane();
  pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

  pane.add(enterBDayL);
  pane.add(enterBDayTF);
  pane.add(userAgeL);
  pane.add(userAgeTF);

  pane.add(clearB);
  pane.add(calculateB);

  setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  setLocation(LEFT,RIGHT);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);
}

private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
//This method is where the age calculation happens
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     String rawBirthday = enterBDayTF.getText();
     try{
      String[] birthday = rawBirthday.split("/");
      int birthMonth = Integer.parseInt(birthday[0]);
      int birthDay = Integer.parseInt(birthday[1]);
      int birthYear = Integer.parseInt(birthday[2]);
     }

     catch(NumberFormatException x){
        System.err.println("Invalid Birthday Format: " + x);
        enterBDayTF.setText("");
        userAgeTF.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a birthday in the form MM/DD/YYYY");
     }
      String[] birthday = rawBirthday.split("/");
      int birthMonth = Integer.parseInt(birthday[0]);
      int birthDay = Integer.parseInt(birthday[1]);
      int birthYear = Integer.parseInt(birthday[2]);

     int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     int currentMonth= cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     currentMonth++;
     //The current month has to be incremented because in this library
     //they count the months starting from 0. Without incrementing the
     //month, the program works perfectly fine, except for birthday's
     //in the current month, where the age is not calculated properly.

     int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

     if(currentYear == birthYear)
        userAgeTF.setText("" + 1);
        //this checks to see if the user's birth year is equal to the
        //current year, if it is, it returns one for the user's age
        //since the user's birthday would have already passed.

     if(currentMonth < birthMonth){
        int age = currentYear - birthYear - 1;
        userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
     }
     if(currentMonth > birthMonth){
        int age = currentYear - birthYear;
        userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
     }
     if(currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay < birthDay){
        int age = currentYear - birthYear - 1;
        userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
     }
     if(currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay >= birthDay){
        int age = currentYear - birthYear;
        userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
     }
     //this block of if statements is used to handle if the user's birthday
     //has passed for the current year or not. 


     }
}

private class ClearButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     userAgeTF.setText("");
     enterBDayTF.setText("");
  }
}



public static void main(String[] args){
  AgeCalculator ac = new AgeCalculator();     

}

}
```

Comment: Exception is coming from line number 82. Integer.parseInt function. Since this is a run time exception that is why compiler is not forcing you to catch it.

Comment: Hey Randy, welcome to SO! Your post seems fine, only thing I'd want to point out is try posting a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This means only post relevant code that way people can solve your problem faster without having to sort through all the stuff we don't need. For example, in this case all the JButtons and graphics objects seem like they may not be needed for the purpose of the question so they could be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for that info!

Comment: @Randy_E no problem. Also, another piece of advice is when you want to communicate with a user specifically, tag them like I did in the beggining. Otherwise, they don't get a notification for the message. Anyways, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are handling the exception, but your code continues to assume that valid date was provided.

> at
>   AgeCalculator$CalculateButtonHandler.actionPerformed(AgeCalculator.java:82)

Move the code after the catch to within the try. You can't split the text if there is not text to split.

Corrected method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String rawBirthday = enterBDayTF.getText();
    try {
        String[] birthday = rawBirthday.split("/");
        int birthMonth = Integer.parseInt(birthday[0]);
        int birthDay = Integer.parseInt(birthday[1]);
        int birthYear = Integer.parseInt(birthday[2]);

        int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentMonth++;
        //The current month has to be incremented because in this library
        //they count the months starting from 0. Without incrementing the
        //month, the program works perfectly fine, except for birthday's
        //in the current month, where the age is not calculated properly.

        int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (currentYear == birthYear)
            userAgeTF.setText("" + 1);
        //this checks to see if the user's birth year is equal to the
        //current year, if it is, it returns one for the user's age
        //since the user's birthday would have already passed.

        if (currentMonth < birthMonth) {
            int age = currentYear - birthYear - 1;
            userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
        }
        if (currentMonth > birthMonth) {
            int age = currentYear - birthYear;
            userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
        }
        if (currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay < birthDay) {
            int age = currentYear - birthYear - 1;
            userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
        }
        if (currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay >= birthDay) {
            int age = currentYear - birthYear;
            userAgeTF.setText("" + age);
        }
        //this block of if statements is used to handle if the user's birthday
        //has passed for the current year or not.

    } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Birthday Format: " + x);
        enterBDayTF.setText("");
        userAgeTF.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a birthday in the form MM/DD/YYYY");
    }
}
```

The thing to remember is that an Exception is thrown when trying to process the String. If the String cannot be processed because it doesn't follow the required Pattern then you must handle the latter logic as if you're unable to continue.